# Why does a 4-bonded nitrogen atom appears negatively charged after an optimization?

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I have a molecule bearing a quaternary ammonium and I optimized it using M062X (also Hartree-Fock) using basis sets 6-31G(d,p) and 6-31G+(d,p) respectively. After optimization, I expect that the charge on the quaternary nitrogen would be positive. However, it's negative.

I ran the Gaussian to compute NBO charges and analysed the checkpoint files as well as log files. Nowhere could I see a positive charge on any nitrogen atom.

Why is this happening? And how can I obtain a positive charge on the quaternary nitrogen?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the positive charge, then?

Comment: What charge to the hydrogen atoms carry? How does the charge distribution differ from a neutral ammonia molecule?

Comment: Run a calculation with neutral ammonia, and you will see it, indeed. I just verified by running the same calculation.

Comment: Also, to understand the reason behind this behaviour, it could be a wise suggestion that of considering the concept of electronegativity

Comment: @IvanNeretin looks like only the total charge is positive.

Comment: Now that's quite outside the realm of things that can be. Isn't the total charge the sum of atomic charges?

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, that's what I also assume.

Comment: @The_Vinz well, I think this is surprising. Nitrogen in neutral ammonia should be negative, if not neutral, as it's quite electronegative. For a quaternary nitrogen, however, it should be positively charged as its lone pairs are also shared by a an additional hydrogen.

Comment: Indeed, the electron pair is shared with a proton (charge +1). But nitrogen is still more electronegative than hydrogen, so two effects occur: 1.the proton sucks electrons from N's pair, and its charge tends to decrease 2.Nitrogen, electronegative, "wants" back its electrons: so its charge increases, but to a limited extent.
As you can see, in neutral ammonia, N is around -1. When ammonia is protonated, charge delocalizes over all its atoms because of the two effects described.

Comment: Another system that you could study, with different electronegativities but similar processes occurring is methylene (:CH2) vs its protonated form, the methyl cation (CH3+)

Comment: @The_Vinz thank you very much. What I later realized is that my molecule bears a cationic imine, not a quaternary nitrogen. However, the same thing happens here. I expected a positive charge, but it's negative. I think your explanation still applies.